# Can't get my python hangman game to count guesses

Tags: python

```
import random

# DEFINITIONS
name = str(input("Welcome to python hangman! What's your name?"))
print("Hello,", name + "!")
print("You have 6 chances to guess the letter in the word, best of luck!")


def get_guess():
    l = input("Guess a letter!")
    if len(l) != 1 or l not in             'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ':
    print("That is not a letter, try again.")
    get_guess()
elif l in guessed:
    print("You have already guessed that letter, try again.")
    get_guess()
else:
    guessed.append(l)
    return l

def check_guess(l):
for i in range(len(word_as_list)):
    if l == word_as_list[i]:
        word_as_blank[i] = l
if l in word:
    print("This is correct")
else:
    print("sorry this letter is not in the word")
    curr_guess = 0
    while curr_guess != 6:
        if curr_guess < 6:
            curr_guess = curr_guess +1
            print("you have had", curr_guess, "guesses")
        else:
            print("you have run out of guesses")

# VARIABLES AND LISTS


secret_lists = ["chicken", "python", "monkey", "giraffe", "panda", "tiger",  "fire", "christmas", "newspaper", "rudolph", name,"aoife"]  # secret words
word = random.choice(secret_lists)
word_as_list = list(word)
word_as_blank = ["_"]*len(word_as_list)
guessed = []

# MAIN PROGRAM

print(word_as_blank)
while word_as_list != word_as_blank:
   guess = get_guess()
   check_guess(guess)
   print(word_as_blank)
print("GAME OVER – you got the word.")
```

The curr_guess currently just prints that they have had 1,2 3 guesses all at the same time i dunno how to do it one at a time, so that when they get the letter wrong it says what guess they are on.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices aside you need to set `curr_guess` variable as a global variable (like `word_as_list`, `word_as_blank`, `guessed`, etc). Then modify your `check_guess` like so:

```
...
print("sorry this letter is not in the word")
if curr_guess < 6:
    curr_guess = curr_guess +1
    print("you have had", curr_guess, "guesses")
else:
    print("you have run out of guesses")
```

Comment: it come up with an error saying local variable curr_guess referenced before assignment

Comment: Move all those variables to someplace right after the import statement.

Comment: I'm still getting this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Weekly Programmes/aoife2aoife.py", line 51, in <module>
    check_guess(guess)
  File "F:/Weekly Programmes/aoife2aoife.py", line 31, in check_guess
    if curr_guess < 6:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'curr_guess' referenced before assignment

Comment: @aoifec250 Look at the solution Man H posted. That should work for you. The issue was not defining cur_guess as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried that and it works**

```
#You have to make cure_guess global 
global cur_guess = 6
#Print out message
print("Sorry this letter is not in the word")
if curr_guess > 0:
    curr_guess -= 1
    print("You still have", curr_guess , guesses) 
else:
    print("You have runned of guesses")
```

Comment: am i using the wrong python? I get this                                                global curr_guess=6
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You will create global cur_guess out of check_guess. After that you will write global cur_guess and in next line you will give cur_guess=6 the value you want . Was mine mistake you use correct python

Comment: I did i put it under import random

Comment: global cur_guess 
cur_guess = 6  This code should be in your def check_guess

Comment: Try to cur_guess =6 out of check_guess and go to def check_guess and write global cur_guess and the following code(This should work!)  print("Sorry this letter is not in the word")
if curr_guess > 0:
    curr_guess -= 1
    print("You still have", curr_guess , guesses) 
else:
    print("You have runned of guesses")

Comment: it does but it only minuses once not everytime

Comment: Be sure that you are using a global variable because global variable hold the price you set to the variable after the end of def call. So it has to decrement any time you call check_guess